# Soporta metodo GET en vez de POST en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-7, routing

A la hora de realizar el registro en laravel me sale el siguiente error

> "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> GET, HEAD."

Cuando la realidad es que yo no defini ninguna ruta. Sino que estoy haciendo el registro automatizado de laravel/ui. Adjunto código de creación de RegisterController:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'surname' => $data['surname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'nick' => $data['nick'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Las rutas no las definí porque las de laravel/ui ya vienen definidas por defecto.
Adjunto linea de código del formulario que se cierra más tarde como corresponde:

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
```

También cabe aclarar que el modelo ya está configurado con los campos correspondientes:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'surname', 'nick', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    'created_at'=>'datetime',
    'updated_at'=>'datetime',
    'role'=>'user'
];

public function marks(){
    return $this->hasMany(Mark::class);
}

}
```

Las rutas que tengo en el archivo web.php son las siguientes:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Auth::routes();

//Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/registro', function () {
    return view('auth.register');
})->name('register');
```

Comment: Espera, cuales son tus rutas que tienes en tu archivo `web.php` ¿Podrias agregarlas, de favor? :)

Comment: Ahi las añadí ;)

Comment: si pones `php artisan route:list` aparece alguna que coincida con POST y register? En caso afirmativo, cuadra con el action del formulario?

Comment: Ahí estaba el fallo. Estaba indicando a otro register. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado!!!

El problema era que estaba llamando a otra acción register que tenía creada en mi archivo web.php.

Verificar siempre las rutas mediante el comando:

> php artisan route:list

Comment: Como sugerencia ya no uses laravel ui, es un paquete legacy sin soporte

Comment: Que recomendas utilizar? No utilizo laravel 8 porque se me dificulta DEMASIAAADO tailwind css

Comment: usa breeze, en lo personal es mucho mejor tailwind, tiene mas opciones pero bootstrap es mas rapido, aunque puedes usar bootstrap en laravel 8 sin ningun problama, solo debes cambiar en tu laravel mix el require de la libreria css